# How to cross link libraries in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

In a c++ CMake project I have an executable `main` and two libraries `lib1` and `lib2`. A function in `lib1` needs a function from `lib2` and visa versa. Also, `lib1` only contains `.h` files. The `main` executable will use both libraries. When I try and "make" the project, I get an error:
`error: redefinition of ‘void lib1()’.`

The file structure looks somewhat like this

```
/path/to/my/project
├── CMakeLists.txt # Project directory
├── main.cpp
├── Lib1
│   ├── ...files (.h only)...
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt # lib1 cmake
├── Lib2
│   ├── ...source files (.cpp & .h)...
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt # lib2 cmake
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the Project directory includes the following:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(Lib1)
add_subdirectory(Lib2)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
  lib2
  lib1
)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the Lib1 directory includes the following:

```
add_library(lib1 INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(lib1
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(lib1 INTERFACE
    lib2
)
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the Lib2 directory includes the following:

```
add_library(lib2 ${SOURCES} ${HEADERS}) # SOURCES and HEADERS set in lines above

target_include_directories(lib2
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(lib2 
    lib1
)
```

If I had to guess, the issue is it is trying to import lib1 headers twice. Once from lib2 and once in my `main` executable. How do I link the libraries so that isn't an issue?

Comment: `I get an error:` Please post the _full_ error messages with all `notice:` and any other verbatim compiler messages including compiler command line from a verbose build (`cmake --verbose` or `make VERBOSE=1`), `error: redefinition of ‘void lib1()’.` So where is `lib1` function _defined_? Please post the definition and source file location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it's anything related to cmake. Although convoluted (I'd do it in another way  but hey it's your code) I think you are defining the body of a function in lib1 where it should reside in a cpp file.

Make that function `lib1` inline.

```cpp
inline void lib1() {
...
}
```

or alternatively defined it in the header and implement it in a body file

```cpp
//lib1.h
void lib1();
```

Then

```cpp
//lib1.cpp
#include "lib1.h"
void lib1() {
...
}
```

Comment: You were right, I completely misunderstood what the error was trying to tell me. I wasn't aware I had to declare a function as inline in the header file if there was no `.cpp` for it. Thank you!